# How to redraw vim after a function call to the commandline

Tags: vimscript, functions

While doing a fun vim exercise I ran into an odd redraw problem.

```
nmap goo :execute ':call GoogleIt("' . input("What would you like to google?: ") . '")'<cr>

function GoogleIt(content)
        silent execute "!ggl " . a:content 
        redraw
endfunction
```

Silent works, but the redraw function only redraws the first line of the file that I was working in. Any suggestions or answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple fix, simply add an `!`.
Change:

```
silent execute "!ggl " . a:content 
        redraw
endfunction
```

to:

```
silent execute "!ggl " . a:content 
        redraw!
endfunction
```

From `:help redraw`

When ! is included it is cleared first.

Comment: If anyone is interested in the full code including the bashrc for how I google from vim just let me know.

Comment: Could you explain what the `!` difference make?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078538/refresh-vim-buffer An answer given by Benj